# How to use dart Map.fromEntries() constructor?

Tags: dictionary, constructor, dart

I'm trying to learn the Dart programming language.

I didn't understand the `Map.fromEntries()` factory constructor. Looking for an usage example.

link : [Map.fromEntries()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.fromEntries.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Map.fromEntries`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.fromEntries.html) constructor is intended to use for creating a map by generating a sequence of pairs.

You *can* use it to create a map from another map as `Map.fromEntries(otherMap.entries)`, but that's wasteful. You can just do [`Map.from(otherMap)`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.from.html).

It's more interesting if you calculate the entries from something else (which may or may not itself be entries).
Example:

```
Iterable<int> someInts = [2, 7, .... ];
var squareMap = Map.fromEntries(someInts.map((n) => MapEntry(n, n * n)));
print(squareMap[7]);  // prints 49.
```

Or you can filter the entries somehow:

```
var filteredMap = Map.fromEntries(otherMap.entries.where((e) => e.key.isOdd));
```

You can often get the same effect by using [`Map.fromIterable`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html) or [`Map.fromIterables`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterables.html), it all depends on which primitives you have available. Filtering the entries of an existing map is particularly easy using `Map.fromEntries`, whereas creating a new map from scratch is probably equally easy using `Map.fromIterable` or `Map.fromIterables`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it right. I think it's a very unused method. Information is information